# C# UWP Async binding

Tags: c#, asynchronous, binding, uwp

I have a problem in UWP (Windows 10) with binding and async methods. I have a checkbox that is bind to one boolean `isDay`. When I change `isDay`, the checkbox is also changing its state.

My code in XAML looks like this:

```
IsChecked="{x:Bind isDay, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

When `isDay` is changed in async method, the checkbox is not changing its state.

What should I do to make this binding to work with async methods?

Comment: Please show all the relevant minimum code including the property declaration and code changing it.

Comment: Post the async method please.  There's a way to do it but you're not going to like it.  If you want to bind on an asynchronous method of any type you should show a state of the checkbox as changing, then once updated notify the property and let the change take place.

Answer (score 5):

In my experience, the underlying cause of the checkbox not changing is the property change notification not firing on the UI thread. I believe UWP swallows the failure rather than throwing an exception about "accessing something from a different thread."

If you already have easy access to a `Dispatcher`, (your code-behind or another view-level component) then you would do something like:

```cs
private async void ClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    bool checked = await SomeAsyncWorkThatReturnsBool().ConfigureAwait(false);
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => checkbox.IsChecked = checked);
}
```

---

#### But what if I don't have a `Dispatcher`?

More likely, you're asking because of async work in a view model, model, or another layer that doesn't actually have access to a `Dispatcher` (or the correct `Dispatcher` when there are more than one). In the past, I've used **dependency injection** and abstracted the interface to give my view models access to the UI thread, however this is arguably a code smell.

My current favorite approach (would love feedback) is to capture the `SynchronizationContext` during the event registration, and use it to post the change event.

```
public class BindableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly List<(SynchronizationContext context, PropertyChangedEventHandler handler)> _handlers = new List<...>();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
    {
        add => _handlers.Add((SynchronizationContext.Current, value));
        remove
        {
            var i = 0;
            foreach (var item in _handlers)
            {
                if (item.handler.Equals(value))
                {
                    _handlers.RemoveAt(i);
                    break;
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    protected Task RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var args = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
        var tasks = _handlers
            .GroupBy(x => x.context, x => x.handler)
            .Select(g => invokeContext(g.Key, g));
        return Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        Task invokeContext(SynchronizationContext context, IEnumerable<PropertyChangedEventHandler> l)
        {
            if (context != null)
            {
                var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
                context.Post(o =>
                {
                    try { invokeHandlers(l); tcs.TrySetResult(true); }
                    catch (Exception e) { tcs.TrySetException(e); }
                }, null);
                return tcs.Task;
            }
            else
            {
                return Task.Run(() => invokeHandlers(l));
            }
        }
        void invokeHandlers(IEnumerable<PropertyChangedEventHandler> l)
        {
            foreach (var h in l)
                h(this, args);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My friend you are a genius! Where did you find/read about this style of working around async and bindings... it works a treat, no other code needs to change (in terms of bindings or business logic) but now I want to know more that I am missing!

Comment: @ChrisSchaller I don't think I read about the impact of the binding difference in UWP. It may be documented that INPC needs to be on the UI thread, but I'm not sure. As to the style of working around it? It was an idea I had that just so happened to work really really well.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason binding is not updating when values are updated via async methods. So, at the end of async method I just use:

```
Bindings.Update();
```

and controls are updated with latest values.

Answer (score -1):

By default auto generated XAML code doesn't support awaitable methods, so you can't use `Task<T>` methods to bind in XAML.

Comment: I found a way. I just put Bindings.Update() at the end of the async method and it is updating binding.

Comment: It's not good solution as for me. I guess need to change logic with this case.

Comment: "find this part in pagename.g.cs and insert ..." is of course ridiculous. You don't change generated code.